# How to flatten a list in NMaximize?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following function:

```
FitModelKnownMomentsNaiveD2[dist1_, dist2_, m_, v_, delta_, p_, AListList_] := NMaximize[{
    D2[
    Flatten[TotalStoppingProbabilities[-Infinity, p, delta, 1, 
        dist1[m, v], #] & /@ AListList], 
    Flatten[TotalStoppingProbabilities[-Infinity, beta, delta, 
         1, dist2[m, v], #] & /@ AListList]
    ], 
    beta > 0, beta < 2}, {beta}
]
```

The D2 function should receive two lists of equal lengths as its two arguments. The first argument works as intended, TotalStoppingProbabilities is applied to each of the elements in AListList and returns a nested list, which is then flattened by Flatten. In the second argument of D2 however, it seems that Flatten is applied before beta is determined by NMaximize, then only afterwards beta is determined and TotalStoppingProbabilities is evaluated, leaving me with the nested list, but unable to flatten it.

To make it more clear, here is the behavior I desire:

1. NMaximize guesses a value for beta
2. TotalStoppingProbabilities (in the second argument of D2) is evaluated using this guess, producing a nested list
3. Flatten flattens the list

But instead, I get the following behavior (I think):

1. AListList is applied to TotalStoppingProbabilities, but since beta is still unknown, TotalStoppingProbabilities is not evaluated, leaving me with a list of the form {TotalStoppingProbabilities[-Infinity, p, delta, 1,
   dist2[m, v], AListList[[1]]], TotalStoppingProbabilities[-Infinity, p, delta, 1,
   dist2[m, v], AListList[[2]]], etc...}
2. Flatten is applied to this list, since the list only has one level, this effectively does nothing.
3. NMaximize guesses a value for beta and evaluates TotalStoppingProbabilities, leaving me with a nested list.

Comment: If you look at the documentation for `NumericQ` and you scroll down to the orange `Applications` and you click on that and you look at the example which says "Define a function that only evaluates when its argument is numeric" then could you perhaps think of a way to use that to try to force your `D2` function to require that `beta` be given a value before `D2` does anything? I can only guess, because I can't see your definition of `D2` but I am assuming that will mean you need to change the definition of `D2` slightly. If that worked then do you think that might solve your problem?